# Automatically skip video in youtube when error occurs using YouTube Android SDK

Tags: android, video, onerror, android-youtube-api

I am trying to build an app that plays a list of videos. Its a very basic implementation based on the API samples.

The playlist (array of video_ids) gets loaded using `player.loadVideos` method. Changes in the player state are tracked using an implementation of `PlayerStateChangeListener`.

Everything works great, and the videos play back-to-back (as expected).

When there is an error in playing the video, (eg. `YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason.NOT_PLAYABLE`), it gets captured in the `onError` method of `PlayerStateChangeListener`, and I call `player.next()` there to move on to the next video.

However, `player.next` does not work after there is an error - basically once there is an error, there is nothing that I can do that would skip that video and play the next one that is queued up in the playlist.

Answer (score 1):

When a player error occurs while YouTubePlayer plays a playlist, calling next() has no effect. I believe this is because errors in YouTubePlayer are non-recoverable. The solution is to reload the playlist with the next playlist index.

So, to keep track of the current playlist index,

```
@Override   // YouTubePlayer.PlaylistEventListener
public void onPrevious() 
{
    mPlaylistIndex--;
}

@Override   // YouTubePlayer.PlaylistEventListener
public void onNext() 
{
    mPlaylistIndex++;
}
```

Then, in onError(),

```
@Override   // YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener
public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) 
{
    Log.d(TAG, "YouTubePlayer error: " + errorReason);

    // Check if the mContentId is of kind video or playlist,
    // if video, there is nothing you can do, end playback.

    // Check if the mPlaylistIndex is the last video in playlist,
    // if so, there is nothing you can do, end playback.

    mPlaylistIndex++;
    mYouTubePlayer.loadPlaylist(mContentId, mPlaylistIndex, 0);
}
```